# Laravel Advanced Wheres how to implement wheres from different table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, laravel

So I have two table and this is the column that they have

TableA = id, slug, user_id, friend_id, parent_id

TableB = id, user_id, friend_id

This is my example coding

```js
$tableA = TableA::where('slug', '3')->first();

$tableB = TableB::where( function ($query) use ($tableA) {
    $query->where('user_id', $tableA->user_id);
    $query->where('friend_id', $tableA->friend_id);
    $query->where('tableA.parent_id','=','2');
})->exists();
```

It seems like only this two where conditions are working

```js
$query - > where('user_id', $tableA - > user_id);
$query - > where('friend_id', $tableA - > friend_id);
```

The last where conditions didn't work. Anyone know what wrong in my coding

```js
$query - > where('tableA.parent_id', '=', '2');
```

Comment: Hi, there is no column named "tableA.parent_id" in table I think thats why it does not work and I did not understand why are you putting this check I mean what do you want to do

Comment: Theres a column parent_id in TableA actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In last condition you write condition for tableA. It will not work.

You can try this

```
$tableA = TableA::where('slug', '3')->where('tableA.parent_id','=','2')->first();

$tableB = TableB::where( function ($query) use ($tableA) {
    $query->where('user_id', $tableA->user_id);
    $query->where('friend_id', $tableA->friend_id);
})->exists();
```

Also I'm recommending you try make this logic with one query, using join or subquery. You can read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#subquery-where-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

try with this query

```
$query->where($tableA->parent_id, '=', '2');
```

it's because tableA is a variable, not a relation

Comment: Is there a way if I want to make it at before })->exists(). 
Something like this 
})$query->where($tableA->parent_id, '=', '2')
->exists();

Comment: I think @Aro already post the answer. for addition, you can use conditional like if ($tableA != null) { //$tableB... }